# Swift - Cambiar entre los tipos de cámaras (wide, telephoto, etc.)

Tags: swift

Tengo una app que inicia con un modo de cámara seleccionado (WideAngleCamera) y un simple botón para hacer el cambio a las otras posibles cámaras (TelephotoCamera, etc.), el problema que nunca cambia, siempre me muestra el tipo de cámara seleccionado al inicio.

```
class CustomCameraController: UIViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    
    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    private var cameraTypeOption = "wide"

    private func setupCaptureSession(){
        let captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice!
        if cameraTypeOption == "wide"{
            captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
        }else{
            captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInTelephotoCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
        }
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                    captureSession.addInput(input)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("Failed to set input device with error: \(error)")
        }
            // Resto de configuración
        
    }
}
```

Hasta aquí inicia todo bien con la cámara WideAngleCamera o si configuro TelephotoCamera desde el inicio igual funciona bien.
Al presionar el botón para alternar entre ambas cámaras, se ejecuta lo siguiente:

```
@objc private func changeCameraType(){
    cameraTypeOption = (cameraTypeOption == "wide") ? "telephoto" : "wide"
    captureSession.stopRunning()
    if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(100) {
        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    setupCaptureSession()
}
```

Cambio el valor de la variable para que se configure la otra cámara, detengo la cámara, incluso remuevo el `View` de la cámara y vuelvo a ejecutar el método que configura todo sobre el uso de la cámara, pero nunca cambia, siempre me muestra la cámara que se configuro en el inicio.
¿Que más necesito cambiar, para alternar tan simple como en la app nativa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si agregas un punto de interrupción en la función `setupCaptureSession` en esta línea:

```
if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
```

No va a entrar porque solo se permite tener un solo `input`. Lo puedes comprobar comentando y dejando la línea en donde se agrega directamente.

La solución está en crear el objeto `session` cada vez que modificas el `input`.

```
private func setupCaptureSession(){
        let captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice!
        if cameraTypeOption == "wide"{
            captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
        }else{
            captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInTelephotoCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
        }
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            captureSession = AVCaptureSession()//Creas nuevamente el objeto
            captureSession.addInput(input)//Agregas el input sin necesidad de verificar porque el objeto está vacío.
            
        } catch let error {
            print("Failed to set input device with error: \(error)")
        }
            // Resto de configuración
        
    }
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probé tu solución y también funciona bien, gracias por responder.

Answer (score 1):

Resolví el problema, el detalle estaba en que me faltaba remover la cámara configurada de la sesión actual antes de intentar agregar la nueva configuración.

```
let currentInput : AVCaptureInput = captureSession.inputs[0]
captureSession.removeInput(currentInput)
```

Quedando el método con los siguientes cambios:

```
@objc private func changeCameraType(){
    captureSession.stopRunning()

    let currentInput : AVCaptureInput = captureSession.inputs[0]
    captureSession.removeInput(currentInput)

    cameraTypeOption = (cameraTypeOption == "wide") ? "telephoto" : "wide"

    setupCaptureSession()
}
```